# Entropy change of Surrounding during adiabatic free expansion process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I recently learnt the Change in entropy of System in adiabatic free expansion process is positive and can be calculated using existing formulae
Also the book i read claims that $$\Delta S_{surr}=0$$ for the same process.
I know that $$\Delta S_{surr}=\frac{Q_{surr}}{T_{surr}} =-\frac{Q_{sys}}{T_{surr}}$$
My initial thought was that this might be because $$ Q_{sys} =0  $$ is true for a adiabatic process but i suddenly realised that this is only applicable in case of  a reversible process which adiabatic free expansion is not.
So how is it true that $$\Delta S_{surr}=0$$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In an adiabatic free expansion the surroundings is isolated from the system. Thus there can be no change in any of the properties of the surroundings, including entropy.

Answer (score 1):

If the surroundings do not exchange heat or work with the system during the actual process, its change in state is zero.  So the entropy of the surroundings does not change.

Comment: Is there a way to quantify this argument using the known formulae?

Comment: What formulas did you have in mind?  What is your understanding of how to determine the change of entropy for an irreversible process for either the system or surroundings?

Comment: If you are looking for a cookbook recipe on how to determine the change in entropy for either the system or the surroundings experiencing an irreversible process, here it is :  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Answer (score -1):

This can be understood as following:
According to the Joule's experiment,  the temperature of the gas doesn't change in this process ($T_{i}=T_{f}$). Thus there is no heat transfer between the gas and its environment:
$$\Delta Q=0\,\,\,\,\,\rightarrow\,\,\,\,\,\Delta S_{surr}=0$$

Comment: yes , but isnt it necessary for  it to be a reversible process for telling that ΔQ=0→ΔSsurr=0  (adiabatic free expansion is irreversible)?

Comment: It is true that the process of free expansion in the gas system is irreversible, but it is conceivable that the surrounding environment is in thermal equilibrium at a constant temperature. As @Chet Miller mentioned, the surrounding system only occupies a fixed point on its "equation of state surface"; i.e.; Delta U=Delta S=0. Although the gas system undergoes free expansion, surrounding system remains at the same point. In other words, no thermodynamic transformation occurs in the it. Then why does its entropy change?

Comment: To emphasize: the surrounding system remains at the same point, since Delta Q = W = 0 for that.

Comment: The Joule experiment assumes the gas is adiabatic, not isothermally.Even in isothermal processes, you can have heat exchange.  Plus, if the gas is non-ideal, the temperature can change in the joule experiment.

Comment: Yes the process was not isothermal and I didn't use the isothermal assumption in my statements either. I just thought about the setup of the experiment (insulating walls,...). Actually the free expansion is an out of equilibrium process, however, Joule observed that Tf=Ti.

Answer (score -3):

Your question is related to what kind of processes can be in the "environment". The usual definition and assumption is that *all* processes in the environment are reversible. The assumption is based on the approximation that the thermodynamic system under investigation, say, an internal combustion engine, is negligibly small in all its thermodynamic quantities in comparison to those in its atmospheric environment with which it is in pressure, thermal, chemical etc., energetic interaction. These energetic interactions are then no more significant to the overall state of the environment (for an ICE, the atmosphere) than its own internal equilibrium fluctuations would be.

I am not saying that the local atmospheric random fluctuations are as large as the exhaust of an engine, say. Rather I am saying that from the point of view of the atmosphere their significance is negligible. Another way of saying is that the local disturbance in the immediate neighborhood of the system, where the interaction takes place, should quickly disappear, much quicker than the rate at which the system operates, this is the quasi-static assumption for the *environment*. Under this assumption, the thermodynamically varying system always sees an equilibrium environment of fixed thermodynamic potentials, such as pressure, temperature, etc.

Furthermore, if your system's process is *adiabatic* then, by definition, there is no entropy exchange with its environment and all other energetic interactions be it mechanical, chemical, electric, etc., are reversible for the environment and consequently within it there is no internal entropy production either.